# Como passar um ponteiro de double como argumento e retornar ele da função C++

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro

Tenho uma função que preciso que ela seja `void` e que um poteiro de double seja retornado dela pelo argumento.

```
void cracking::decompose(char input[][100], int size_S, double* &Atm, int* &ID, int &size_out);
{
vector<double> AtmD;
vector<int> XsD;
...


    Atm = &AtmD[0];
    ID = &XsD[0];
    size_out = size(AtmD);

}
```

na Main ela fica:

```
int main()
{
    char oi[900][100] = { "1  0.5 C", "2  0.55 N", "3  .5  S" };
    double* xAtm = NULL;
    int* xXs = NULL;
    int tamanho;
    cracking calc;


    calc.decompose(oi, 3, xAtm, xXs, tamanho);



    return 0;
}
```

apesar de compilar ela me retorna valores completamente errados. Existe algum modo de fazer isso com os ponteiros?

De fato percebi que os ponteiros de dentro da minha função viram lixo quando retorno eles para o main. Existe alguma forma de manter os ponteiros salvos? Por exemplo, se salvo o endereço `0x000000000029d680` na memoria e ele corresponde ao 23.5, quando eu saio da função esse endereço ja não corresponde a esse valor e vira lixo, existe um modo de manter esse valor?

Comment: o que tentaste fazer com `double* &aponta`? Tenta `double *aponta` apenas. Outra coisa, para retornar valor, tua função tem que indicar o tipo de retorno, e não `void`. Passagem por referência não é retorno

Comment: Eu preciso que ele seja como double &valor, so que ao inves de ser um argumento de double que ele seja um ponteiro de double para que eu consiga inputar ele mas tambem pegar de volta o valor resultante dele como funciona para o int &tamanho

Comment: "Eu preciso" não é justificativa. Diga o que tentaste fazer aqui, e por que é necessário apontar para o endereço de uma variável em vez de apontar para a variável. Estou com a impressão que tu não estás sabendo o que estás fazendo - nesse caso, tua melhor ajuda seria um [bom livro de C](http://index-of.es/C++/C%20How%20to%20Program.pdf).

Comment: Possuo um vector<double> e preciso apontar para o primeiro double desse vetor, dessa forma eu consigo pelo ponteiro do primeiro elemento e o numero de elementos pegar todo esse meu vetor de volta. Não é viavel que eu tenha uma função  do tipo vector<double> pois em alguns casos tenho mais de um vetor, struct também não é viavel.

Comment: Precisamos ver o trecho de código onde a função é chamada

Comment: Fiz as alteracoes

Comment: Atm e id retornam lixo, porque os vetores Atmd e Xsd são destruidos no retorno da função. Você realmente precisa do endereço desses vetores? Não basta o valor do primeiro elemento? Essa assinatura de função é criação sua ou passaram para você? Não costumo encontrar uma referência para um ponteiro como parametro de função.

Comment: Marcos, preciso de todos os elementos do vetor mas não posso passár o vetor nem como retorno nem como argumento pois vou externar essa função em C. Qualquer coisa que funcione para pegar o vetor inteiro seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Nesse caso, acho melhor você substituir os vetores por arrays do C. E você vai ter que definir quem vai liberar essa memória mais tarde.

Answer (score 0):

A questão é que ambos `vector<double> AtmD;` e `vector<int> XsD;` são alocados na pilha quando o seu método `decompose` é chamado. Assim que este método retornar, o contexto da função é destruido assim como os dois vetores alocados. Logo, estes endereços apontam para lixo.

Se você realmente precisa fazer isto, você pode alocar uma array `static` (como em C) para que a array não seja destruida na saída, entretanto esta solução não é thread-safe. Você também pode alocar os vetores na `main` e passar para a sua função.